# WebRTC and socket.io: Why doesn't my code reconnect a person after they disconnect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, p2p

i am trying to connect them to a random person. When I connect two people (I open two windows, accept camera, and click connect on each) it works fine, it connects them and displays the remote video.

But after a person clicks disconnect, the remote video from the other person turns into a black square, which makes sense, but the other person sees a "frozen" remote video, so not a black square.... Why is this?

Also, if I click connect on both of the windows again, it just doesn't work. No matter how many times I click connect on each window. Those two people will not get connected to anyone again, until I refresh the whole thing and go through this again. I also tried opening up another window, and clicked connect, with the hope that it would connect to the person who just disconneected and clicked connect, but it didn't.

Why can't they connect again after they go through disconnect? It seems like they can only ever connect to someone once, and then if they want to connect to another person, they have to refresh the entire page and start over.

Client code: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2918
Server code: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2919

Comment: Please include all relevant information *in the question*. While outside resources can help answerers find the problem, please include as much information in the question itself because links can change and break.

Comment: Sometimes my code is too much to write out, so it's a lot easier to copy and paste into an uploader. I will try to include as much as I can if there's less code. Do you know why I can't reconnect a webrtc connection?

Comment: If you can't distill the relevant code down to portion that is practical to paste into your question, then you probably need to work on your question so it's more specific to a particular piece of code.  StackExchange doesn't work for generic questions like "why doesn't my app work?" and it works very well for specific questions about a specific piece of code like "why doesn't this code generate output X?"  As it stands now your question is far too much like the former and not close enough to the latter.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm just not sure where in my code there's a problem. I figured out the whole getting a black square video on both ends, but I still can't get another connection after both people first click disconnect, and then connect.